# Python webbrowser module on raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-webbrowser

My problem is very simple.
When I start python modules that use `webbrowser.open("anywebsite")`, all works perfectly, but when I put it on a module that is started by cron at the startup of the rpi, when it comes to execute this line, nothing shows up. Not even an error, so here I am and I don't know how to make it works. I hope my English was clear, I'm sorry if not.
Have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open any website by typing the name, for example, If you type google, the script will open a google tab. If thats the problem, I have codes that might helps you.

```
#pip install webbrowser
import webbrowser

website = input("Please type the name of the site ")
webbrowser.open("https://www." + website ".com")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, my problem is that the code works fine on the others OS and even when I run it from a shell. So I think this is a problem with crontab.

Comment: Would you add your code also, so we can find out where the problems are.